# MySQL JDBC Driver multiple threads executing commands concurrently, best to use thread pooling?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

Currently I have created a series of automation tests (Selenium & Java) which run in parallel; i.e. x5 tests will run concurrently via separate threads.

Some of the tests will interact with the target database (MySQL) and in turn perform specific SQL write commands; i.e. create new users directly via the database.

It seems when running the tests concurrently not every thread is writing too the database, even though the SQL write statement is correct and by reducing the thread count to one, I no longer run into the issue.

My Code:

```
public static void createDatabaseConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + Db_Settings.getAddress() + ":" + Db_Settings.portNumber
                    + "/" + Db_Settings.getDbEnvironment() + "?" + Db_Settings.ssl, Db_Settings.getDbUsername(), Db_Settings.getDbPassword());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getStackTrace() + ", " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void closeDatabaseConnection() {
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getStackTrace() + ", " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Example command (Combo); which can be called by x2+ separate threads at the same time:

```
DbManager.createDatabaseConnection();
DbManager.executeSqlUpdateStatement(Account.createAccount_Sql_Script());
DbManager.closeDatabaseConnection();
```

Any advice on whether I should be using thread pooling or synchronise when making database connections via: MySQL JDBC Driver?

Comment: The pattern very likely will cause connection leak in multi-threaded environment. Imagine `DbManager.createDatabaseConnection();` was called again when `DbManager.closeDatabaseConnection();` wasn't called yet, the con static global variable will be assigned with new instance. Imagine `DbManager.executeSqlUpdateStatement(Account.createAccount_Sql_Script());` threw an exception too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Jayr would you be able to provide any guidance / code changes on my current implementation?

Comment: Also @Jayr each thread will have their separate instance of  DbManager.createDatabaseConnection(); and DbManager.closeDatabaseConnection(); and I ensure I close the connection when calling the logic within a given Java method. So example1() - will always create and then close the connection.

Comment: Hi @SamP are you allowed to refactor DbManager? Minimally I will try to do make it such that the pattern will be like:      `try (Connection con = createDatabaseConnection()) {
      DbManager.executeSqlUpdateStatement(con, Account.createAccount_Sql_Script());
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Your can use Hikari jdbc pool library. It allows you create several connectiots to database and run sql queries in parallel without connection conflicts, and without connection leaks.